# Pose Estimation relative to initial Pose

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have a set of image point and corresponding 3d object point and i use a single calibrated camera to find the pose.Using `SolvePnP()` i could calculate the R and T also the camera position using the formula `Position = -R.t()*t`.  Now my question :
I would like to calculate a initial pose and after that whatever pose i calculate should be relative to the initial pose i calculated.How can i do that?
Any ideas or suggesion will be Appreciated.

Comment: You mean, you'd like to determine how much the camera got moved?

Comment: @Niko that was my task. But the values i was getting was not so accurate. So i thought it may give better result when it has a initial reference point

Answer (score 0):

It does help. You might want to use RPP:

http://www.emt.tugraz.at/publications/EMT_TR/TR-EMT-2005-01.pdf

This imposes certain smoothness on the pose, and mainly used for tracking purposes.

The code is here : http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=576